# How long does it take for a new custom CocoaPod to get uploaded to the pod trunk?

Tags: cocoapods, trunk, cocoapods-app

I just uploaded a new CocoaPod but it does not show up when I search for it on CocoaPod.org.
How long would it take for it to show up on search?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've had it take 3 hours up to 24 if its the first time. First time takes forever. Updates are quicker usually take place within 2-3 hours.

Comment: So, does `pod 'PODName'` and `pod install` will not work for that time? Or it's just the time that it takes in the listing but we can use it? It's just I added a public pod `RPTTextView` and it's up successfully but when I run `pod install` with it shows `Unable to find a specification for RPTTextView` error.

Comment: From my experience you need to wait a couple hours to be able to install a custom pod update from the trunk, the listing on cocoapods.org took forever the first time I uploaded a spec

Answer (score 2):

My updates usually take over 8 hours. Just updated one today...7 hours so far and counting.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023: first time publishing (`pod trunk push`) took about 40 min to become available with `pod install --repo-update`